# CSS 404 not found google app engine

Tags: python, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, google-app-engine

i am using google app engine (python) to develop my web application, now i found a little problem. I would like to add bootstrap css file to google app engine, and here is my folder directory

- project

  - app.yaml
  - favicon.ico
  - index.yaml
  - main.py
  - templates

    - css

      - bootstrap

        - css

          - bootstrap.css
  - images
  - js
  - header.html
  - signup.html
  - welcome.html

app.yaml code

```
application: project
version: 1
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: yes

handlers:
- url: /favicon\.ico
  static_files: favicon.ico
  upload: favicon\.ico

- url: /templates/css/boostrap/css/
  static: boostrap.css


- url: /.*
  script: main.app

libraries:
- name: webapp2
  version: "2.5.2"

- name: jinja2
  version: latest
```

in my header.html css link like this

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

when i refresh my page, it only shows the plain text, css file is 404 not found. Any help?

Comment: Your yaml file has a different url than your header.html

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
- url: /css/bootstrap/
  static_dir: /templates/css/bootstrap/css
```

and reference it via

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/bootstrap/bootstrap.css" />
```

Comment: i try your advice, but it is not working, besides on this, i am curious about what is the "url" and "static_dir" refers to...thank you

Comment: I had a typo (now fixed). The idea is that the urls start with /css/bootstrap, and map to a directory in the app that is templates/css/bootstrap/css/

I copied this, with an unfortunate typo, from a working app of mine.

For the meaning of `static_dir`, see the doc. https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/getting-started/serving-static-files